# How to run alert in Chrome before page completely loads, but after it starts to?

Tags: javascript

Having tried `alert` statement in Firefox, I tested it in Chrome.

```
<body>
    <p>
        B
    </p>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        alert("Javascipt!");
    </script>
    <p>
        E
    </p>
</body>
```

Unlike Firefox, Chrome ran the `alert` immediately on page opening, whereas the desirable result is to show the first `p` tag, then execute the `alert` statement, and after clicking OK show the rest of HTML. I know that script actually is being executed where placed, and the following proves this:

```
<body>
    <p>
        B
    </p>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.write(1);
    </script>
    <p>
        E
    </p>
</body>
```

*output: B 1 E*

.. but I want exactly `alert` to run between these paragraphs. Is there a way to do so in Chrome?

Comment: What is the actual use case you need this for?

Comment: Note that what you're trying to do (i.e. putting `<script>` in the middle of the `<body>`, particularly one that does `document.write` or `alert`) is generally not the best idea, as it is blocking the HTML parser and the construction of the document object model (DOM), and it's best to be avoided in any public-facing websites.

Comment: @jakub.g
I don't need anything like that for real reasons, it's just for practice (I don't need it now, but may later) and  for testing functionality of browsers (i.e. if I can make it at all).
Thanks for advice, I would unlikely use it in a real project, but I wonder if it is possible.